# Как сделать DIV шире родителя без сдвига контента родителя?

Tags: css, css3, вёрстка

Делаю так:

```
.child {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
right: 0;
}
```

Все работает, но контент родительского DIV сдвигается под **.child**, и его не видно. Можно ли сделать, чтобы не сдвигался?

Comment: Ваш вопрос не ясен. Добавьте пожалуйста полный код, с описанием желаемого результата.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
section {
  width: 60%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 1em;
  background: silver;
}

div {
  margin: 0 -3em;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .25);
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>
    Как сделать DIV шире родителя без сдвига контента родителя?
    Как сделать DIV шире родителя без сдвига контента родителя?
    Как сделать DIV шире родителя без сдвига контента родителя?
    Как сделать DIV шире родителя без сдвига контента родителя?
  </div>
</section>
```